# WPF ItemsControl doesn't refresh when I use PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have list of strings and a property for it, only with `get` that returns `List<string>`.  So, when I add something to my list and call `OnPropertyChanged("NameOfProperty")` it does not refresh my `ItemsControl` in the view, but when I add something in the constructor it works.

MainWindow

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   DataContext = new MainWindowModel();
}
```

MainWindowModel C#

```
private static List<string> messages = new List<string>();
public List<string> Messages
{
   get
   {
      return messages;
   }
}

// ...

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
   if (PropertyChanged != null)
   {
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}

// ...

public void foo()
{
   messages.Add("Hi");
   OnPropertyChanged("Messages");
}
```

MainWindow XAML

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Messages, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression

```
messages.Add("Hi");
```

does not change the value of the `Messages` property, and unless the property value has not actually changed, the PropertyChanged event is ignored.

In order to update the UI when a collection is modified (i.e. elements are added, moved or removed), the collection needs to implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface. The framework provides the `ObservableCollection<T>` class that implements this interface.

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Messages { get; }
    = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

and just

```
Messages.Add("Hi");
```

Answer (score 0):

Collection Properties which should notify the framework, that items were added or deleted must implement the interface [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=netcore-3.1).

A default implementation is found in the [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netcore-3.1).
So you could change your Messages Property Type to ObservableCollection instead of List.

Answer (score -1):

Changing lists to ObservableCollection should be enough.

Comment: What does this add over and above the two previous answers to this question?